# assets:precompile with uglify fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, bower, aws-opsworks

Any idea how I can fix this error?

### Environments

- Server: EC2 (OpsWorks Rails App)
- OS: Amazon 2014.09
- Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [x86_64-linux]
- rails: 4.0.8
- bower-rails: 0.9.2 （I've tried the latest code from the master branch too, but did not work）
- npm: 1.4.28
- bower: 1.4.1
- ExecJS.runtime: I've tried RubyRacerRuntime and Node.js, but none of them works on my server

### Note

- `assets:precompile` works fine on my local machine (mac) somehow
- The only way I found to make asset:precompile work on my server is comment out `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`. (But I want to uglify)
- precompile always fails in `bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js` (If I manually fix syntax error in intro.js, then get the error for outro.js)

### Error

```
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.017580 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/event-53bd66b3ef4e0030febbf883c4ccab1e.js
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.034631 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/event/ajax-2728c2aeb59d870e60923e2a75492611.js
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.057426 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/event/alias-b8026dcda8af25a845c9aaf6b812a0c3.js
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.073036 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/event/support-7331020932640489d80faa12a4510a96.js
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.093488 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/exports/amd-4a5f196c0022a5f22de3dd642af82512.js
I, [2015-07-10T06:54:41.131496 #21463]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/public/assets/jquery/src/exports/global-fa942be8ff1d0bcc250cff98e5c45509.js
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 46, col: 0, pos: 1394)

Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2357:10736)
at js_error (<eval>:2357:10955)
at croak (<eval>:2357:18667)
at token_error (<eval>:2357:18804)
at unexpected (<eval>:2357:18892)
at block_ (<eval>:2357:23918)
at ctor.body (<eval>:2357:23572)
at function_ (<eval>:2357:23637)
at expr_atom (<eval>:2357:26669)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:2357:29262)
(in /srv/www/app/releases/20150710064958/vendor/assets/bower_components/jquery/src/intro.js)/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:34:in `rescue in block in eval'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:28:in `block in eval'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:80:in `block in lock'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `call'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `Locker'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `lock'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:27:in `eval'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.1/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:19:in `exec'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `really_compile'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
/home/deploy/.bundler/app/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
---- End output of bundle exec rake assets:precompile ----
Ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile returned 1
[2015-07-10T06:54:44+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) because `assets:precompile` does not work on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: You are using Capistrano? (That's how I found this page)

In this case (and for those using Capistrano): I had exactly this issue when I tried using the default configuration. Whenever I executed `cap production deploy:assets:precompile`, it would throw the error above. Executing `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` would still work on the deployment machine (if manually executed).

My fix was overriding the Capistrano job:

```
Rake::Task["deploy:assets:precompile"].clear_actions
class PrecompileRequired < StandardError; end

namespace :deploy do
  namespace :assets do
    desc "Precompile assets if changed"
    task :precompile do
      on roles(:app) do
        #invoke 'deploy:assets:precompile_changed'
        within release_path do
          execute <<-EOCOMMAND
            (cd #{release_path}/vendor/assets
             bundle exec rake assets:precompile)
          EOCOMMAND
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

From this moment on, it worked. My guess is, that Capistrano defaults to a different version of rake or uglify (maybe the one installed globally).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I remember, I got the error even when I manually run `assets:precompile` command without Capistrano. (I've been using asset_sync, so let me try again sometime later.)